# In Swift 4 for MacOS X, how to embed NSStackView in NSBox?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift4

I'm trying to rewrite an IB application as mostly code instead of a Storyboard, because some controls will be dynamically created. I'm currently stuck trying to embed a `NSStackView` (or actually anything other than `NSView`) in the controlView of an `NSBox`. I know IB can do it, because my current app has:
Highlighted an `NSBox`, containing a View, containing a Stack View.

[image: Highlighted an NSBox, containing a View, containing a Stack View]

In my example app I can embed a the label in the box successfully (i.e. set the box's contentView to the `NSTextView`)

Then I tried to embed a stack view in the box and it says it's not the expected type (`NSView`). So I created an intermediate `NSView` to hold the stack view, just as in the real app. If I try to add the stack view to the `NSView` as a subview, I get "Cannot convert value of type..."

Is there a way to embed the stack view in the box?
Or is there a way to embed the stack view in a view which I can then embed in the box?

Here is the relevant part of my current example code:
code and error message.

[image: code and error message]

Comment: Please post relevant code in question instead of posting a URL to image.

Comment: did my answer help? Could you please accept it if it helped?

Comment: Your answer just said I should be able to do what I said I was unable to do. That was not helpful.

Comment: Eventually I gave up trying to embed views in NSBox as a way of showing the bounds of the view. Instead I am formatting the a border around the stack view itself after learning about "backing views" (enabled by "wantsLayer"). For example:
`let sv = NSStackView( views: noViews )
view.addSubview(sv) // Add it before configuring it
sv.wantsLayer = true
sv.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.lightGray.cgColor
sv.layer?.borderWidth = 1`

Comment: you should check my answer again. That is not true. You were trying to add an Array of Stacked view as `innerView.addSubview( sv)` instead of doing `interView.addSubview(content)` as mentioned in my answer. That is what you did wrong. See that I have used `content` not `sv` as mentioned your question. That is the answer to this question. I am not sure how that is same as your question when you have declared `sv` as `var sv = [NSStackView]()` which is an Array.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error in image in question, you should try below code:

```
interView.addSubview(content)
```

You cannot add an array of stack views directly on view using `addSubview` since it only accepts view of type `NSView` or its subclasses. You can iterate through the array and add each view on it using this method instead.

You can also add `NSStackView` as `contentView` of `NSBox`. It shouldn't create any issues.

[image]